# How do I make a function that is called on every contract call? – Solidity

Tags: function, call, solidity, contract

I need to make a function that will be called each time someone called my contract. And I need to do it without using modifiers because there are many functions in my contract and I use third-party contracts.

How can I do it?

Comment: Currently `solidity` does not have any life cycle hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit third-party contracts and make a new child contract and then modify each function with a modifier you defined in the child contract, that's the only way to do.

Example:

```
Contract ThirdParty {
    address owner;

    function f() public {}
}


Contract Child is ThirdParty {

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function f() public onlyOwner {}
}
```

Comment: But how to modify functions of the parent contract with the modifier defined in the child? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, I'll write an example.